# Have relative path in bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to have relative path w.r.t to a certain path(lets say /home/krg85/stackoverflow) as my bash prompt. ie If i am in a folder /home/krg85/stackoverflow/abc/cde, my prompt should be `user@host abc/cde$` . I would also love to extend it so that if i am on a path /home/krg85/github, my prompt will be `user@host /home/krg85/github$` instead of being `user@host ../github$`.

Comment: Er, kindly disregard this comment. I misread the question. If you were in /home/krg85 (and not in the stackoverflow subdirectory), what would you like the prompt to display? '..'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
PS1='\u@\h $(pwd | sed "s@^/home/krg85/stackoverflow/\?@@")\$ '
```

Comment: +1! But note that if the user is in /home/krg85/stackoverflow, the 'pwd' command won't output a trailing '/' and the prompt will contain the full path. Consider tacking a "\?" onto the end of the first sed regular expression.